# Shopware 6: How to only display order comment icon if a comment is entered

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, shopware, shopware6

I  am working on a Shopware 6 store and want to customize the order list view. Specifically, I want to only display the comment icon if an order has an actual comment entered.

By default, the comment icon shows on every order. I need it to be conditional so it only displays when there is a comment.

[image: Image of the icon]

Here is the code I tried in the `app/administration/src/module/sw-order/page/sw-order-list/index.js`:

````js
import template from './sw-order-list.html.twig';

Shopware.Component.override('sw-order-list', {
    template,
});```

And my twig template looks like:
```html
{% block sw_order_list_grid_columns_order_number %}
    {% parent %}

    <template #column-orderNumber="{ item }">
       {#{% dump( "item") %} #}
            <sw-button
                {# v-if="item.customerComment && item.customerComment.length > 0" #}
                {{ dump( item.customerComment) }}
                v-if=" item.customerComment  !== null  "
                v-tooltip="{ message: item.customerComment }"
                class="sw-order-list__tooltip-order-comment"
                size="x-small"
            >
                <sw-icon
                    name="regular-comments"
                    size="14px"
                />
            </sw-button>
    </template>
{% endblock %}
````

This overrides the order list and adds a computed property to check for comments.

However, item.customerComment always has Null or maybe I can not access it from the default shopware twig file. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: If the icon is still showing up then it seems likely that `this.order.comment` is not equal to empty string.  It could be null or undefined and the condition would still be true.  Do you know what the value of `this.order.comment` actually is?

Comment: I have updated the question. Kindly have a look.